# Can you access ArcScan from a python script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arcscan

I'm using a python script with ArcPy in ArcGIS 10, and want to access some ArcScan functions.

Is this possible? I can't see anything in the documentation about it, but I can't really find any very good ArcPy documentation.

**Update:** Just to add some extra information: I want to run the centreline vectorisation method (see [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/using_the_centerline_vectorization_method/000w0000002p000000/)) from an ArcPy script. Is that possible?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this? I can't seem to find any documentation for it, but I can't quite believe that it isn't possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [ArcGIS 10.0 Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Essential_ArcPy_vocabulary/000v000000v6000000/) it appears that there are only three ArcPy modules (mapping, sa - Spatial Analyst, and ga - Geostatistical Analyst).

To this was added [arcpy.na (Network Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mr00000012000000) at 10.1.

I read this to mean that ArcPy can be used to access a fair amount of mapping functionality from core ArcGIS Desktop, as well as more from the Spatial, Geostatistical and Network Analyst extension products.

ArcScan is just one of a number of ArcGIS Desktop extensions lacking an ArcPy module at the moment.