# What are common methods for converting raster digital elevation data to vector contours?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, elevation, contour, topography

In researching this I have found many references to the opposite, creating elevation data from contours, but nothing regarding contour creation. Preferably, I am looking for open source solutions like QGIS, Grass or command line tools but I am open to any suggestions that will get me pointed in the right direction.

I am planning to take the contour data into a vector drawing app for line formatting but if the app can do some of that as well it would be a major time saver.

Comment: did you look in qgis at the menu raster ->extraction ->contour?

Comment: Thanks, this is about the same as Aaron's advice. It works great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are looking to convert DEMs to contour lines:

- QGIS Plugin [Contours](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/contours/)

For converting scanned topo maps to vector contour lines, Arcscan is one of the easiest (and most sophisticated) programs out there.  However, there are several opensource alternatives, including a promising GRASS approach:

[Trace vector contours from a scanned map](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Trace_vector_contours_from_a_scanned_map).

Additional information can be found here:

- [Scriptable alternative to ArcScan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/5256/8104)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I love the fact the conversion can be scripted.

I've got a lot of learning to do with QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

I think that GRASS module [r.contour](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.contour.html) has more functinality than QGIS' one. For example, you can set maximum and minimum levels for extracting contours. Plus, it has parameter *cut* which makes the output more generalized.

Answer (score 3):

Another open source option which can easily be scripted using shell scripts or python is to use [GDAL_Contour](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html) to generate contours from a dem file. I grabbed some example DEM data and ran this command to generate 10 m contours, saved as a shapefile:

```
gdal_contour -b 1 -a elevation -snodata -9999 ns67ne.tif contour.shp -i 10
```

The switches are:

- `-b 1` selects the band of the image to process, which defaults to 1
- `-a elevation` is the name of the contour elevation attribute which will be created
- `-snodata -9999` tells GDAL the value of nodata cells in the input raster, so they can be ignored
- `ns67ne.tif contour.shp` are the input and output files, respectively
- `-i 10` is the spacing between each contour

Comment: Apparetly QGIS uses GDAL_Countor, so it's like QGIS works as frontend to GDAL_Contour.

Comment: I didn't know that, good to know!

Comment: Not only is it a frontend for gdal_contour, QGIS shows the exact gdal_contour parameters that it will run and allows you to edit them before running it.